# Do the Java Collections.unmodifiableCollection preserve the order of the underlying collection?

Tags: java, collections

I assume that as the unmodifiable methods in Collections return a view or facade of the underlying collection. It appears to be self evident that `unmodifiableList` will use the underlying list's order and `unmodfiableSet` is at liberty to do anything as there is no ordering.

I am using a `LinkedHashSet` which is a set but does preserve the ordering and am trying to expose an unmodifiable view of the collection that preserves the underlying ordering. Using `unmodifiableSet` does not seem appropriate but I cannot use `unmodifiableList`. I am unable to find a guarantee that `unmodifiableCollection` will use any ordering in the underlying collection though I suspect it will.

Can anybody point me to a specification that defines this behavior or contradicts it?

Comment: On further investigation in this case I could use a Guava UnmodifiableSet instead as the set is created as part of object construction and that collection retains insertion ordering which is unaffected by "later" duplicate entries. However, that only covers my particular case where the set is created during construction and never updated.

Answer (score 4):

The call to `Collections.unmodifiableXXX` simply creates a thin wrapper that throws exceptions when mutating method calls are made. All other method calls go through to the underlying collection, so there's nothing else that would affect ordering or other things except the original collection.

The wrapper has no state, it only has a reference to the underlying collection.

The entire `UnmodifiableSet` wrapper is very small, and as the iterator (inherited from `UnmodifiableCollection`) uses the iterator from the underlying collection (except it overrides `remove()`), the iteration order is exactly the same as in the original collection.

```
static class UnmodifiableSet<E> extends UnmodifiableCollection<E>
                             implements Set<E>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9215047833775013803L;

    UnmodifiableSet(Set<? extends E> s)     {super(s);}
    public boolean equals(Object o) {return o == this || c.equals(o);}
    public int hashCode()           {return c.hashCode();}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman I'm sure it is going to do everything I want it to do as the docs say that all query operations read through to the specified collection. I guess that query in this case includes iteration order but I'd sort of like to find that defined as being true is some sort of docs. The LinkedHashSet is defined as using a list to preserve the element insertion order but I can't make an unmodifiableList view of it.

Comment: Of course you can't. It's not a `List`, it's an `OrderedSet`.

Comment: Quite, it just uses one to maintain the insertion order, but there's no Collections.unmodifiableOrderedSet so I have either Set or Collection. Set to me implies the mathematical concept which has no implied ordering but if either actually guarantees keeping the ordering of the underlying collection that's perfect. I'm just looking for the reference documentation of that guarantee

Comment: You might not find any guarantee (beyond the javadoc's "operations 'read through' to the underlying collection). But considering that they're meant to be used as drop-in replacements for the concrete collections, it would be a pretty bad design choice to go out of your way to alter the behaviour of the underlying collection. You could trust that the implementation is everywhere at least as sane as in the JDK, or waste time looking for some guarantee that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I'll stop looking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) for Set Class:

> Unmodifiable Sets: The iteration order of set elements is unspecified and is subject to change.

Comment: It's not relevant for the question, though, is it?